# Как проверять объект на пустоту

Tags: javascript

```js
var salaries = {
  "Вася": 100,
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 250
};

function maxsalary(obj){
 var sum = 0;

 for(var key in salaries){
  if(sum < salaries[key]){
   sum = salaries[key]
  }
 }
 var d = sum + ' ' + key;
 return d;
}
console.log(maxsalary(salaries));
```

> Есть объект `salaries` с зарплатами. Напишите код, который выведет имя сотрудника, у которого самая большая зарплата.
>
> Если объект пустой, то пусть он выводит «нет сотрудников».

Не знаю как сделать чтобы выводила «нет сотрудников», если объект пустой

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg  еще не проходил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var salaries = {
  "Вася": 100,
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 350
};

function maxsalary(obj){
    var max = null,name ='';
    for(key in salaries){
        if (max <= salaries[key]) {
            max = salaries[key];
            name = key;
        }
    }
    return name ? max + ' ' + name : 'нет сотрудников';
}
console.log(maxsalary(salaries));
```

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно задать значение по умолчанию для `d`, перед циклом.

В этом случае, если объект пустой, в цикл не зайдет и значение `d` не изменится.

Кроме того, в функции сейчас не используется переданный параметр, а используется глобальная переменная. Это тоже нужно исправить.

Пример:

```js
var salaries = {
  "Вася": 100,
  "Петя": 300,
  "Даша": 250
};

var salariesEmpty = {};

function maxsalary(obj) {
  var sum = 0;
  var d = 'нет сотрудников';

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (sum < obj[key]) {
      sum = obj[key];
      d = sum + ' ' + key;
    }
  }
  return d;
}
console.log(maxsalary(salaries));
console.log(maxsalary(salariesEmpty));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxsalary(obj){
    var t = Object.keys(salaries).length == 0;
    var sum = 0;

    [salaries].filter((v, i, e) => {

        cobst arr = [];
        const keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for(const key of keys) {
            arr.push(v[key]);
        }
        const max = arr.sort().reverse()[0];
        sum = max;
        return v;
    })
    return t ? 'Нит никаво' : sum; 
}
```